# Powershell SMO changing database context from master when setting database to SINGLE_USER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, powershell, smo

I am trying to set a database to single user using SQL Server SMO and have the code below. This code is an abridged excerpt from a larger restore script

```
$Credential = Get-Credential

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null;
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null;

$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server "MY-SERVER1";
$srv.ConnectionContext.NonPooledConnection = $true;
$srv.ConnectionContext.ConnectTimeout = 0;
$srv.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 0;

$srv.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = $false;
$srv.ConnectionContext.set_Login($Credential.username);
$srv.ConnectionContext.set_SecurePassword($Credential.password);
$srv.ConnectionContext.DatabaseName = "master";

$srv.ConnectionContext.Connect()

($srv.ConnectionContext.ExecuteWithResults("SELECT DB_NAME(),@@SERVERNAME")).Tables # verify database and servername we are connected to

$srv.Databases.Item("MyDB").UserAccess = "Single";
$srv.KillAllProcesses("MyDB");

try
{
    $srv.Databases.Item("MyDB").Alter([Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.TerminationClause]::RollbackTransactionsImmediately);
}
catch
{
    Write-Host $_.Exception.GetBaseException().Message;
    Write-Host "";
}

$srv.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();
```

The account I pass into `$credential` has the following permissions in SQL Server:

```sql
GRANT CREATE ANY DATABASE TO [MyUser]
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO [MyUser] 
GRANT ALTER ANY DATABASE TO [MyUser] 
GRANT ALTER ANY CONNECTION TO [MyUser]
ALTER SERVER ROLE [dbcreator] ADD MEMBER [MyUser]
```

When I run the Powershell code above, it fails on the `$srv.Databases.Item("MyDB").Alter` line with the error

> The server principal "MyUser" is not able to access the database "MyDB" under the current security context.

when I open a profiler trace, I can see that it is running `USE [MyDB]` and `MyUser` doesn't exist in that database which explains the error.

if I wanted to do this in Management studio, I would run the `ALTER DATABASE` statement against the master database:

```sql
USE master;
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB]  SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

which works when run as `MyUser` in SSMS.

How do I stop the SMO alter command trying to switch the database context to the `MyDB` my user doesn't have access to?

If possible, I am looking to amend the existing code using SMO, rather than re-write using `Invoke-SqlCmd` or something else as this script is used extensively in production. The script was written originally using SMO as that was the best way identified to Set a database to single user mode and Restore the database using the same SPID

Comment: can't you just use Invoke-Sqlcmd ?

Comment: I thought about using Invoke-SqlCmd, however, this SMO script is currently in production so I would like to amend it if possible rather than a full re-write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the PowerShell / SMO side of things, *but* there is something you can do that will work without requiring any modification to the PowerShell script. Just allow `MyUser` to connect to any database (without adding that login to any particular database) by granting the `CONNECT ANY DATABASE` instance/server -level permission:

```sql
GRANT CONNECT ANY DATABASE TO [MyUser];
```

I don't see this as a security risk given that you're already granting this login the `CREATE ANY DATABASE`, `ALTER ANY DATABASE`, and `VIEW SERVER STATE` permissions.

For example:

**SETUP**

```sql
USE [master];
CREATE LOGIN [MyUser] WITH PASSWORD=N'Pop-Pop';

GRANT CREATE ANY DATABASE TO [MyUser]
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO [MyUser] 
GRANT ALTER ANY DATABASE TO [MyUser] 
GRANT ALTER ANY CONNECTION TO [MyUser]
ALTER SERVER ROLE [dbcreator] ADD MEMBER [MyUser]
```

**TEST 1**

```sql
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = N'MyUser';

USE [_SecurityTest];
-- error (as noted in the question)

REVERT;
```

**APPLY FIX**

```sql
GRANT CONNECT ANY DATABASE TO [MyUser];
```

**TEST 2**

```sql
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = N'MyUser';

USE [_SecurityTest]; -- Success!

SELECT USER_ID(), SESSION_USER;
-- 0    MyUser
-- 0 = public role

REVERT;
```

Comment: Hi @solomon, thanks for this. This will probably be a suitable workaround if an SMO solution isn't possible. What I didn't want to do was explicitly create the user in every database I need to restore but your GRANT CONNECT ANY DATABASE is a bit cleaner than having to do that :)

Comment: @SEarle1986 Hi there. Makes sense to wait for a PowerShell/SMO answer, but it looks like one isn't being provided (and this doesn't look like something that would be easily resolvable at the PowerShell/SMO level). It might be too late, but would you consider either accepting my answer or awarding the bounty? Else it will default to only awarding 50% if the time runs out. Thanks.

Comment: awarded - thanks

Comment: - Apologies, it looks like I only accepted the answer, not awarded the bounty. I though accepting it awarded the bounty
Sorry

Comment: @SEarle1986 Is quite ok. I didn't say anything because the system automatically awards the full bounty to an accepted answer so long as that answer was posted within the bounty period. So in a sense, accepting does award the bounty, just not immediately. If you want to award the bounty to a non-accepted answer, or an accepted answer that was posted prior to the bounty being created, then you must do that manually. So, thanks for accepting .

Comment: OK great - thanks! (not sure of a use case you would want to award a bounty to a answer that wasn't the accepted answer but who am I to question!)